# New textfield not coming while clicking add new in a loop in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This is my html block in angular

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]">  
<div class="choice-div" ng-if="webfront.customer_fields[$index].input_type == 4">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">Choices : </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">                                                    
        <div ng-repeat="textBox in webfront.customer_fields[$index].webfront_field_values" class="addtext-div">                                                       
            <input ng-model="textBox.value" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5 addtext_box" type="text" id="{{textBox.id}}" required=""  placeholder="Value" autocomplete="off" style="width: 40%;">
            <span  ng-click="removeTextBox(webfront.customer_fields[$parent.$index].webfront_field_values, $index, textBox.id)" style="margin-left: 20px;cursor: pointer;"> <i title="Cancel this option!" class="raty-cancel cancel-off-png" data-alt="x"></i></span>
        </div>   
        <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success" ng-click="addTextBox(webfront.customer_fields[$index].webfront_field_values)"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-plus"></i> Add Option</span>
        <br class="clear"/>                                                     
    </div>
</div>
```

```
This is my output of json formatted angular data

webfront{"id":1,"customer_fields":[{"id":24,"webfront_id":1,"name":"CA1","webfront_field_values":[]},{"id":25,"webfront_id":1,"name":"Education","webfront_field_values":[{"id":14,"webfront_field_id":25,"value":"B.tech"},{"id":15,"webfront_field_id":25,"value":"MCA"},{"id":16,"webfront_field_id":25,"value":"MBA"}],"customer_checkbox":true}]}
```

Below i have included the image how is my html

[image: Add option image with data]

While there is data in the input field everthing working fine as i have mentioned above

[image: Add option image with no data]

But while there is no data only add option comes.Also the **Add option** for new text field not working.

I want there should be a text field on the top of the add option come and while click to the **Add option** new text field should come with remove option. Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: need more code ! Post your controller file

Comment: This my response data in controller code

        $scope.webfront = response.data.webfront;
                var cust_length = $scope.webfront.customer_fields.length;
                for ($i = 0; $i < cust_length; $i++) {
                    if ($scope.webfront.customer_fields[$i].webfront_field_values.length == 0) {
                        $scope.webfront.customer_fields[$i].webfront_field_values = [{label: 1}];
                    }
                }